# Fetching the image from aws s3 with signed url

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I uploaded the image from android to aws s3  and found  the generated url from aws and saved it on my server but after some time whe i want to fetch the image with that signed generated url i am getting access denied.

can any one help me about this how can i fetch  image from aws  through that url?

Comment: Because image stored on server folder is password protected so you need to pass username and password along with header when you download the image from server

Comment: thank you for instant reply. please can you send me some code sinnepet or any refference

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way may be help you**

```
public Bitmap getUrlContent(String urlstring) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] imageRaw = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    //your username and password here
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
            }});
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.connect();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c;
                while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
                {
                    out.write(c);
                }
                out.flush();

                imageRaw = out.toByteArray();

                urlConnection.disconnect();
                in.close();
                out.close();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageRaw, 0, imageRaw.length);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```